# Powershell dot notation not selecting data

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm having a problem getting Powershell to behave the way I'm expecting.

I'm trying to use `get-wmiobject win32_networkconnection` to list the mapped drives for the current user, so I can loop through the drives.

When I run `$var = get-wmiobject win32_networkconnection | select -expand localname` I get exactly what I expect:  a list of the drive letters for the mapped network connections.

However, when I run `$var = (get-wmiobject win32_networkconnection).localname` I get nothing.  It doesn't seem to be selecting the property correctly.

This is problematic, because, ideally, I'd like to loop over all the drives, and then select the various properties for each drive.  Instead, it seems like I'll be forced to kludge together an iterator, and then iterate over all the variables one at a time (not very elegant, in my opinion).

I'm not super experienced with Powershell, so there may be something I'm missing.  However, from what I've read, this should be working.  Is this a limitation of `get-wmiobject`?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Both versions return the same thing for me (the list of drives). Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: @briantist Powershell 2.  Most of the machines on my network have PS2, which is why I'm using that version.  Is that a limitation with PS2?

Comment: @Nick2253 Yes, dot-dereferencing on collections only work in 3.0 and above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do only works in PowerShell 3.0 and newer versions. The official documentation is *very* vague:

> ## [What's New in Windows PowerShell 3.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857339.aspx#BKMK_Lang)
>
> #### Windows PowerShell Language Enhancements
>
> Windows PowerShell 3.0
> includes many features [...] The improvements include
> **property enumeration**, count and length properties on scalar objects,
> new redirection operators [...]

This blog post goes a bit more into depth: [New V3 Language Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx)

Comment: +1 for it being vague. I remember when I first found this behavior; trying to find official documentation for it was difficult (not knowing the term to search for at that time).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a limitation of PowerShell 2.0.

Your call to `Get-WmiObject` is returning an array. In PS2, you would need to pipe the array into something like `Select-Object` or otherwise iterate over it and reference each individual item.

In PS3+, you can use `$array.PropertyName` and it does that for you, returning an array of properties.

Answer (score 0):

intead of select propertyName, you can use select -exp propertyName